# How to turn a string into an XML file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing to a XML file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453105/writing-to-a-xml-file-in-java)

I have below XML text as a string.

```
<someNode>
    <id>A124</id>
    <status>404</status>
    <message>No data</message>
</someNode>
```

I have above XML data as a String. Is it possible to convert the text into an XML file and archive the generated XML file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class StringToXML {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"></soap:Envelope>";  

     DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  

    DocumentBuilder builder;  
    try  
    {  
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  

        // Use String reader  
        Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource(  
                new StringReader( xmlString ) ) );  

        TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
        Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();  
        Source src = new DOMSource( document );  
        Result dest = new StreamResult( new File( "xmlFileName.xml" ) );  
        aTransformer.transform( src, dest );  
    } catch (Exception e)  
    {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}
```

This information is helpful.

Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 1):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(theString)));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The asker wants to write the xml string to a file, not parse it into a document.

Comment: Diego, actually the asker is not clear. `convert the text into an XML file` and `archive the generated XML file`, since he already have a xml file in a string, he might want to parse the content of the string, I also understand that he just wanted to save the file to the disk in the first read.

Answer (score 0):

You can, use the `java.io.FileWriter` to save your file.

```
String fileData = "<sample><xml>data</xml></sample>";
File outputFile = new File("someFile.xml");
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try{
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
    bw.write(fileData);
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    try{bw.close();}catch(Exception e){}
}
```

In case you need to manipulate the xml do like **Kazekage Gaara** said:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(theString)));
```

And to save you can do as I said above. To transform the document back to string:

```
fileData = doc.toString();
```

Comment: The BufferedWriter and File are unnecessary. You are writing only once, so you can just do fw = new FileWriter(filename) and write to that.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple as that:

```
String text = "<your><xml>data</xml></your>";
Writer writer = new FileWriter("/tmp/filename.xml");
writer.write(text);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29).  It has a single method that will do everything you need.

Code would look something like

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("filename.xml"), xml);
```