# Write a xml in java

Tags: java, xml, file, remote-access, fileoutputstream

I need to write an xml file which is located in the **191.160.100.122/Test/conf/test.xml**

The java code I am using is ,

```
public static void writeXml(PropertyForm propForm , LinkedList flaglist , LinkedList list){

    try{
        String filePath = "http://191.160.100.122/Test/conf/test.xml";
        URL url = new URL(value);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();


        XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(os);

        writer.writeStartDocument();
        writer.writeStartElement("xmldata");

        writer.writeStartElement(propForm.getBuss_hrs_name());
        writer.writeStartElement("StartTime");
        writer.writeCharacters(propForm.getBuss_hrs_start());
        writer.writeEndElement();
        writer.writeStartElement("EndTime");
        writer.writeCharacters(propForm.getBuss_hrs_end());
        writer.writeEndElement();

        writer.writeEndElement();

        writer.writeStartElement("Messages");
        for(int i=0;i<flaglist.size();i++){
            System.out.println("======flag=====");
            System.out.println(flaglist.get(i).getPname().length()+"---"+ flaglist.get(i).getPname()+"---"+flaglist.get(i).getKey()+"---"+flaglist.get(i).getVal());

            writer.writeStartElement(flaglist.get(i).getKey());

            writer.writeCharacters(flaglist.get(i).getVal());
            writer.writeEndElement();


        }
        writer.writeEndElement();
        for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++){
            if(list.get(j).getPname()!=null && list.get(j).getPname().equals("Holiday")){
                System.out.println(list.get(j).getPname()+"---"+list.get(j).getKey()+"---"+list.get(j).getVal());

                writer.writeStartElement(list.get(j).getPname());
                writer.writeStartElement("Date");
                writer.writeCharacters(list.get(j).getVal());
                writer.writeEndElement();
                writer.writeStartElement("Name");
                writer.writeCharacters(list.get(j).getKey());
                writer.writeEndElement();

                writer.writeEndElement();

            }
        }
        writer.writeEndDocument();

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above code runs without any exception . But File write process is not done.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: @DownVoter . Please post some comment for down vote. It helps me to know the reason and to correct my issue.

Comment: see this post maybe helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453105/writing-to-a-xml-file-in-java

Answer (score 2):

This is generally not how webservers behave, nor how you publish content to them.

When you perform an HTTP GET for `191.160.100.122/Test/conf/test.xml`, you're contacting the webserver at `191.160.100.122`, port 80, and asking it to give you the resource with the name `/Test/conf/test.xml`.  How the server processes this request, and decides what to return, depends entirely on what the server is, and how it's configured.  (It might read files from a directory, or run some database queries, or execute some code, or theoretically *anything*.)

You will need to look at what the server is, and work out how to make it return different results from this request - and *then* set up your "writer" process to do whatever is necessary to have the new data returned.

---

FWIW your current code is not "failing" because it's not doing what you think.  You're opening a connection to the above URL, and then sending the content through this connection to the server.  That request is "successful", insofar as it completes without error.  But there's no general guarantee that the server will do anything particular with this data you've provided, especially not what you expected.  (In fact unless you explicitly open an HTTP **PUT** connection (rather than the default GET), it would be a bad idea for the server to modify anything on the basis of that request.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Can u give any Ideas to do my requirement ?

Comment: you might want to use other protocols like ftp or scp instead of http.

Comment: @HumanBeing as I said, it depends **entirely** on what the webserver is that you're connecting to.  If it's something like a simple Apache server, then you'd need to create a file in a particular directory on the server's hard drive, using something like scp (as Moh-Aw suggested).  But if it's e.g. a Java servlet container, then this won't work at all and there's no "out of the box" method that would work in this, or many other, cases.